# remove/unbind hover on anchors

Tags: jquery, unbind

**html**

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
```

**css**

```
a {
   color: blue;
}
a:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

now as you can see `<a>` now would be color red on hover.

**Question**
How do I remove hover via jQuery?
I have tried:
`$('a').unbind('hover');` and `$('a').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')`

I come to think why it won't work, is this not `hover()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `a:hover` is not bound event on the anchor tag and is only a pseudo class you won't have success unbinding the .hover() event.

If you want to change the behavior then you can do two things

1. remove the `a:hover` styles
2. bind a hover event on the anchor tag and set the css accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is a CSS rule, not a JavaScript event.
The easiest way to change the color is via a stronger CSS rule, for example:

```
a.NoHover:hover {
   color: blue;
}
```

or

```
body a:hover {
   color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add/remove classes and use JQuery to act accordingly. So you should create classes for both normal and hover state. For example, you can remove styling from the element like this:

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).removeClass();
});
```

But I would suggest you to actually add and remove classes accordingly using:

**[addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)**
  [**removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: I don't think this will work since it is not added as a class.

Comment: `removeClass` will not change the color, but will remove all classes and may wreak havoc on the page's design.

Comment: @Kobi: Actually i am asking him to add classes for normal and hover states as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If its only color you are concerned about this might help.

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.css('color', $this.css('color'));
 });
```

The element's `style` property will override the properties set in any CSS selectors.  The theory [has been tested](http://jsbin.com/uxiki/2) and works fine.  This plugin will read arbitrary css properties and set them back therefore "sticking" them.

```
$.fn.stickCss = function(props) {
  var stick = (props || '').split(/\s+/);
  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each(stick, function(i, prop) {
      $this.css(prop, $this.css(prop));
    });
  });
};

// example usage:
$('a').stickCss('color background-color margin padding');
```