# remove hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please go to below link and click story,

http://premio-e.de/

when I mouse over,

http://awesomescreenshot.com/03b435w09

it's animating on hover.

how do i remove this.
I am using below css for this,

```
.storypageThumb1 {
    float:left;
    width:175px;
    height:91px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background:url(../images/storyPage-thumb01_new.png) no-repeat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.storypageThumb1:hover {
    background-position:0 -91px;
}
```

it's suppose to just change the possition. not animating.

Comment: pro jsfiddle, against clickwhoring!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688701/remove-unbind-hover-on-anchors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In firebug I noticed that all your `a` tags have a transition associated:

`-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;`

That's why it is animating. You have to remove the transition from that element, like:

```
.storypageThumb1 { 
    transition:none; 
    -moz-transition:none; 
    -o-transition:none; 
    -webkit-transition:none; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have set all your anchors to animate on all CSS changes with the following code:

```
a { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; }
```

You can override this at your `storeypageThumb1`:

```
.storypageThumb1 {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) appreciated very much for quick response :D

Comment: Note that `-webkit` is only for webkit browsers. The same would apply to `-moz` etc.

Comment: @user788647 maybe you should finally accept an answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

in this site their is a CSS file called `normalize.css`

```
a {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; // convet this line to -moz-transition: none;
    color: white;
    outline: medium none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

OR
for your `.storypageThumb1` write:

```
.storypageThumb1 {
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler than this!

.storypageThumb1:hover {
    background: none;
}